# cec-command to switch to TV 0 from raspberry pi not working

Tags: hdmi

So my raspi is connected to HDMI port 3 of LG TV. It is recorder 1 and logical address is 1. Phy address is 3.0.0.0
Raspi is on the screen. now I want to switch to TV. A fios box is connected to
the coax input of TV. 
I have tried to switch to TV (0) using:

> > echo "on 0" | cec-client -s -d1
> >     no luck.
> >     echo "tx 1f 82 00 00" | cec-client -s -d1
> >     no luck.

The main message I see as it scrolls which could be an issue is:
"initiator 'Broadcast' is not supported by the CEC adapter. using 'Free use' instead"iinitiator 'Broadcast' is not supported by the CEC adapter. using 'Free use' instead
However googling it has not shown any specific solution to the issue.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can your TV talk CEC?  Courtesy of Wikipedia the LG version may be called SimpLink.

If so is the CEC option turned on on your TV?  I had to turn mine on on my Panasonic.

If you have the time and patience then to test you could download and fire up a version of XBMC on the RPi as this has CEC working out of the box if the TV has it enabled.

Comment: northern-bradley:

Comment: northern-bradley: well, I turned symlink on. i used the remote buttons went to that option and it was on. the other thing is that if it is on TV (0) I am able to switch to the pi by using cec command ("as"). hence i think cec is turned on. also, when I  use tv remote to switch source to tv(0) i do see debug output trace which shows a command to the effect of "0f 82 00 00" which the tv broadcasting itself as the active source. but when I issue that command (1f 82 00 00) where I am trying to put tv back to active, it remains on the pi.

Comment: Sorry but I've never played with the lower level stuff and unfortunately I'm RPi-less to try to see what my TV produces.  Try the RPi forums

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK CEC device cannot choose other source, it can either:

- declare itself as active source (with < Active Source > 0x82 with OWN phys. address)
- or renounce an active source role (with < Inactive Source > 0x9d with again OWN phys. address).

In the last case, TV:

- may display its own internal tuner and send an < Active Source > with 0.0.0.0 (0f820000)
- may choose another device for display
- or, maybe, broadcast for source with < Request Active Source > (0f85) ?